# Generating IL for Recursive Methods

Tags: c#, .net, il

I tried to generate IL for recursive method using following strategy,
Firstly I defined type using following code snippet

```
private void InitializeAssembly(string outputFileName)
        {
            AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(outputFileName);
            assemblyBuilder = appDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName,
                                                              AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
            moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(outputFileName, outputFileName + ".exe");
            typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Public);
            methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Main",
                                    MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public,
                                    typeof(void),
                                    System.Type.EmptyTypes);
            ilGen = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

        }
```

Next I started to generate IL for recursive method as given below.

```
MethodBuilder method = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
                   “MethodName”,
                   MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public,
                   NodeTypeToDotNetType(func.RetType),
                   parameters);
                ILGenerator ilOfMethod = method.GetILGenerator();

method.DefineParameter();
```

For calling method itself inside the method body I used following construct,

```
ilOfMethod.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeBuilder.GetMethod("MethodName", new System.Type[] {typeof(arg1),typeof(arg2),etc}));
```

Finally save generated assembly using following method.

```
private void SaveAssembly(string outputFileName)
        {
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            typeBuilder.CreateType();
            moduleBuilder.CreateGlobalFunctions();
            assemblyBuilder.SetEntryPoint(methodBuilder);
            assemblyBuilder.Save(outputFileName + ".exe");
        }
```

Unfortunately this is not working since recursive method calling construct, inside the method returns null. Issue here is that recursive call inside the method ( i.e. `ilOfMethod.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeBuilder.GetMethod("MethodName", new System.Type[] {typeof(arg1),typeof(arg2),etc}));`
) returns null. Since we actually create the type inside the `SaveAssembly()` method, this is acceptable. So my question is that: is it possible to generate IL for recursive methods using above construct? If it is not possible, Please let me know that alternative constructs for generating IL for recursive methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but if I remember correctly you should be able to simply use the result of `DefineMethod` to emit the `Call` instruction:

```
MethodBuilder method = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("MethodName", ...);
...

ILGenerator ilOfMethod = method.GetILGenerator();

...
ilOfMethod.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method);
```

Comment: Just about to post same. [`MethodBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.methodbuilder.aspx) inherits from `MethodInfo`, so would seem valid there.

Comment: +1 Thanks a Lot! Your suggestion works and I was able to generate IL for recursive methods